# conditional color coding of a textbox in SSRS Report based on date range

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have below columns in my report body and I need to fill background color in a ProviderNextContactDate textbox based on below condition

```
ProviderContactDate    ProviderNextContactDate
  2/3/2022               8/3/2022
  1/6/2022               7/6/2022
  11/18/2022             5/18/2022
```

..

```
if ProviderNextContactDate is past due then Red
if ProviderNextContactDate is within 30 days then yellow
otherwise transparent
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming past due means past on or earlier than today **and** your colums are `Date` or `DateTime` data types, then just set the `backgroundcolor` property of the textbox to an expression something like this...

```
=SWITCH(
        Fields!ProviderNextContactDate.Value >=Today(), "Red",
        DateDiff("d", Fields!ProviderNextContactDate.Value, Today()) <=30, "Yellow",
        True, Nothing
       )
```

The final 'True' acts like an else. 'Nothing' is the default backgroundcolor for textboxes which is effectively transparent.

You may need to adjust the numbers of days or the `>=` and `<=` depnding on your needs. For example, `DateDiff` returns the number of boundaries crossed, in this case the number of days (denoted by the `"d"`).

Comment: Glad I could help. Can you please mark the answer as accepted (the check mark to the left of the answer under the vote up/down buttons. This will help others with similar questions find answers in the future.